# Javascript change variable after changing dropdown list value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do something in javascript as a beginner. I'm making a simple dropdown list, but i can't get it to work. The variables stay 'undefined'. What am i doing wrong?

```
<span class="textmenu">I’m coaching <div class="list"><select onchange="crewclassFunction(this.value)">
  <option value="heavywomen">heavyweight women</option>
  <option value="heavywomen">heavyweight men</option>
  <option value="lightwomen">lightweight women</option>
  <option value="lightmen">lightweight men</option>
```

I'm trying to call the function 'crewclassFunction' when a value changes.

```
function crewclassFunction(crewclass) {

  if(crewclass.value == "heavywomen") {
  var span = 432;
  var innerHandle = 234;
  var bladeAngle = 435;
  var oarLength = 234;
  var overlay = 24;
  var height = 34;
  }

  setResult();

  };
```

And then calling the function 'setResult' to change the variables in the HTML.

```
function setResult() {

  document.getElementById("spanresult").innerHTML= span;
  document.getElementById("handleresult").innerHTML = innerHandle;
  document.getElementById("angleresult").innerHTML = bladeAngle;
  document.getElementById("lengthresult").innerHTML = oarLength;
  document.getElementById("heightresult").innerHTML = height;
  document.getElementById("overlayresult").innerHTML = overlay;
  };
```

Hope someone can help me out! Thanks.

Comment: You declared the variables locally on `crewclassFunction` and you you cant use that on `setResult`. You have to pass it.

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot. :D

Comment: Please check my sample code on my answer below, @Max

Comment: @Max If your code has worked by simply passing the variables as arguments, **then you haven't shared the correct code with us**. You are calling crewclassFunction as `crewclassFunction(this.value)` which means that this method accepts a string rather than an object which has value property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the variables locally on `crewclassFunction` and you you cant use that on `setResult`. You have to pass it as parameters.

```
function crewclassFunction(crewclass) {

  if(crewclass== "heavywomen") {
     var span = 432;
     var innerHandle = 234;
     var bladeAngle = 435;
     var oarLength = 234;
     var overlay = 24;
     var height = 34;
  }

  setResult(span, innerHandle, bladeAngle, oarLength, overlay, height);

};


function setResult(span, innerHandle, bladeAngle, oarLength, overlay, height) {
    document.getElementById("spanresult").innerHTML= span;
    document.getElementById("handleresult").innerHTML = innerHandle;
    document.getElementById("angleresult").innerHTML = bladeAngle;
    document.getElementById("lengthresult").innerHTML = oarLength;
    document.getElementById("heightresult").innerHTML = height;
    document.getElementById("overlayresult").innerHTML = overlay;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line

```
if(crewclass.value == "heavywomen") {
```

You are already passing a value via

```
<select onchange="crewclassFunction(this.value)">
```

So, you don't need to check it's value property again, **simply make it**

```
if(crewclass == "heavywomen") {
```

Also, you need to pass the other local variables is crewclassFunction to the other function otherwise they are not available in setResult's scope.

Even better - just refactor these variables in `setResult` only since you are only using them in this method

```
function setResult() {
  var span = 432;
  var innerHandle = 234;
  var bladeAngle = 435;
  var oarLength = 234;
  var overlay = 24;
  var height = 34;
  document.getElementById("spanresult").innerHTML= span;
  document.getElementById("handleresult").innerHTML = innerHandle;
  document.getElementById("angleresult").innerHTML = bladeAngle;
  document.getElementById("lengthresult").innerHTML = oarLength;
  document.getElementById("heightresult").innerHTML = height;
  document.getElementById("overlayresult").innerHTML = overlay;
}
```

And then call that method as

```
function crewclassFunction(crewclass) {
  if(crewclass == "heavywomen") {
    setResult();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function crewclassFunction(crewclass) {
  if(crewclass == "heavywomen") {
    var span = 432;
    var innerHandle = 234;
    var bladeAngle = 435;
    var oarLength = 234;
    var overlay = 24;
    var height = 34;
  }

  setResult(span, innerHandle, bladeAngle, oarLength, overlay, height);
};

function setResult(span, innerHandle, bladeAngle, oarLength, overlay, height) {
  document.getElementById("spanresult").innerHTML= span;
  document.getElementById("handleresult").innerHTML = innerHandle;
  document.getElementById("angleresult").innerHTML = bladeAngle;
  document.getElementById("lengthresult").innerHTML = oarLength;
  document.getElementById("heightresult").innerHTML = height;
  document.getElementById("overlayresult").innerHTML = overlay;
};
```

```html
<span class="textmenu">I’m coachin</span>
<div class="list">
  <select onchange="crewclassFunction(this.value)">
    <option value="heavymen">heavyweight men</option>
    <option value="heavywomen">heavyweight women</option>
    <option value="lightwomen">lightweight women</option>
    <option value="lightmen">lightweight men</option>
  </select>
</div>


<!-- mock -->
<br />
<div id="spanresult">spanresult</div>
<div id="handleresult">handleresult</div>
<div id="angleresult">angleresult</div>
<div id="lengthresult">lengthresult</div>
<div id="heightresult">heightresult</div>
<div id="overlayresult">overlayresult</div>
```